# mysql GROUB BY idea

Tags: mysql

I have the following scenario: there are 1 table with books and two couples of tables (HD/IT) with Sales Order and Purchase Order transactions connecting through Sales Order id.
The table structure follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isbn` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `it_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kind` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `isbn`, `it_id`, `kind`) VALUES
(1, '12345',    1,  1),
(2, '12345',    1,  2),
(3, '67890',    2,  1),
(4, '1111111',  2,  2);

CREATE TABLE `porders_hd` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt` date NOT NULL,
  `so_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `porders_hd` (`id`, `dt`, `so_id`, `customer`) VALUES
(1, '2017-07-02',   1,  1),
(2, '2017-08-03',   NULL,   3);

CREATE TABLE `porders_it` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dscr` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `porders_it` (`id`, `hd_id`, `isbn`, `dscr`, `qty`) VALUES
(1, 1,  '12345',    'Book 1',   1),
(2, 2,  '1111111',  'Book 2',   1);

CREATE TABLE `sorders_hd` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt` date NOT NULL,
  `customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `sorders_hd` (`id`, `dt`, `customer`) VALUES
(1, '2017-07-01',   1),
(2, '2017-08-01',   2);

CREATE TABLE `sorders_it` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dscr` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `sorders_it` (`id`, `hd_id`, `isbn`, `dscr`, `qty`) VALUES
(1, 1,  '12345',    'Book 1',   1),
(2, 2,  '67890',    'Book 2',   1);
```

In summary there are:
* 1 Sales Order (#1) also existing in the Purchase Order (#1)
* 1 Sales Order (#2) still pending
* 1 Purchase Order (#2) created without a Sales Order

I want to be able to grab all Sales and Purchases Order per book's isbn and the connected SO and PO must be in the same line. The output must be like the one below:

```
so_id   so_date     po_id   po_date     isbn    dscr
NULL    NULL        2       2017-08-03  1111111 Book 2
1       2017-07-01  1       2017-07-02  12345   Book 1
2       2017-08-01  NULL    NULL        67890   Book 3
```

I tried to grab the rows using a query like the one below:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(so_id) so_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(so_date) so_date,
GROUP_CONCAT(po_id) po_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(po_date) po_date,
isbn,
dscr
FROM (

SELECT
hd.so_id        so_id,
NULL        so_date,
hd.id   po_id,
hd.dt po_date,
bk.isbn,
it.dscr
            FROM porders_hd hd,
                 porders_it it,
                 books bk
           WHERE it.hd_id = hd.id
             AND bk.isbn  = it.isbn
             AND kind = 2
UNION
SELECT
hd.id   so_id,
hd.dt so_date,
NULL        po_id,
NULL        po_date,
bk.isbn,
it.dscr
            FROM sorders_hd hd,
                 sorders_it it,
                 books bk
           WHERE it.hd_id = hd.id
             AND bk.isbn  = it.isbn
             AND kind = 1

) as table1
 GROUP BY isbn, so_id, po_id
```

but since there is info missing I get the following result:

```
so_id   so_date     po_id   po_date     isbn    dscr
NULL    NULL        2       2017-08-03  1111111 Book 2
1       2017-07-01  NULL    NULL        12345   Book 1
1       NULL        1       2017-07-02  12345   Book 1
2       2017-08-01  NULL    NULL        67890   Book 3
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this ?

Comment: I'm so confused

Comment: Add `group by ISBN, descr` at the end of the query

Comment: Hi krokodilko. Very fast - thank you :-)

Comment: If a put a new Sales Order for the same ISBN the result is not the expected :-(

Add the following line to books:

5  12345 3 1

add sorders_hd the line:

3 2018-08-05 5

and to sorders_it the line:

and you are getting all 12345 transactions in one line :-(

Comment: I am completely confused too. You should really tidy up your data model. For every minute you spend designing a clean database you save 10 to 28 minutes not running into troubles in the future. Some inconstencies: how can you ever sell the 2nd purchased book (link it to an so), and what happens when you order 3 but sell them 1by1? How can `kind` in `books` mean if it is so/po, when the existence of a row in the so/po-tables already tells you if it's so/po? For your current problem: you need to join so and po (probably using your so-id in po, although as mentioned above, it won't always work).

Comment: Hi Solarflare. Kind tells which table to use for the join: 1 for sorders_it, 2 for porders_it. The multi-order situation does not exists in my case: if the SO has 3 the PO will also have 3. I will try the left joins with the null addon and I  will let you know.

Comment: These were just examples. Keep in mind that normalization does not only exists because it is more beautiful, but because it is (very) useful. E.g. if your quantities are always the same, the model should reflect that and you would only need it in one table. Same as having your `isbn` twice in `books`. Without splitting up `kind`, you could use 1 row in books and the same id in both so and po (and would already have a link between both, which would solve your problem). Although I don't know what `books` actually contains (what happens e.g. if you add another order for the same isbn?).

Comment: But it's ok, keep your data model - just be prepared to redo it completely in half a year (because you probably won't like it anymore yourself then). That's already included in the 10-28 minutes I mentioned.

Comment: I'm not stucked with this data model. I'm just answering yous questions :-) This model comes from the needs of what I'm creating and I have no problem to change it to new.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after, but I can;t figure out the role of `kind` from your code. But here is a query that for each books, gets the associated po line item, finds the corresponding so line item and joins the header rows so the dates are available. Note my assumption that a sales order can't exist with a corresponding PO.

```
SELECT books.isbn, books.descr, sorders_hd.id, sorders_hd.dt, porders_hd.id, porders_hd.dt
FROM book 
join porders_it on porders_it.isbn = books.isbn
join porders_hd on porders_hd.id = porders_it.hd_id
left outer join sorders_it on sorders_it.hd_id=porders_hd.so_id and sorders_it.isbn = porders_it.isbn
left outer join sorders_hd on sorders_hd.id = sorders_it.hd_it
```

You could normalize your tables so that descr need not be repeated, and also use the book.id in the other tables rather than isbn.

Comment: Hi RichGoldMD, thank you for your answer. 

The kind field declares the kind of transaction: 1 for SO, 2 for PO. Also I cannot normalize SO and PO dscr since dscr can be different when a customer is ordering and you are ordering from your supplier :-(

With your query you are loosing "orphaned" Sales Orders. The result is:

isbn dscr id dt id dt
12345 Book 1 1 2017-07-01 1 2017-07-02
12345 Book 1 1 2017-07-01 1 2017-07-02
1111111 Book 2 NULL NULL 2 2017-08-03

Comment: Also I cannot use book.id since the book table keeps all book's transactions. The next order of a book with the same isbn will add a new line to books table:
5  12345 3 1

Comment: SO you have a situation like this: PO <=> isbn <=> SO - but the book record for each is separate. They should be on th same line IFF the isbn is equal and 'sorders_it.hd_id=porders_hd.so_id', correct?

Comment: I posted a new answer, preserving this one because the comments are illustrative,

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a new answer because the previous one and the comments are illustrative. Based on that discussion, this requires a FULL OUTER JOIN which must be emulated by UNION ALL in mysql (which may be what OP was attempting originally).

Here is my new code, taking that into account:

```
SELECT sorders_hd.id as so_id, sorders_hd.dt as so_dt,
porders_hd.id as po_id, porders_hd.dt as po_dt,
books.isbn, porders_it.dscr
from books 
left outer join porders_it on porders_it.isbn=books.isbn 
join porders_hd on porders_hd.id=porders_it.hd_id 
left outer join sorders_it on sorders_it.isbn=books.isbn and sorders_it.hd_id=porders_hd.so_id
left outer join sorders_hd on sorders_hd.id=sorders_it.hd_id
where books.kind=2

UNION ALL 

SELECT sorders_hd.id as so_id, sorders_hd.dt as so_dt,
porders_hd.id as po_id, porders_hd.dt as po_dt,
books.isbn, sorders_it.dscr
from books 
left outer join sorders_it on sorders_it.isbn=books.isbn 
join sorders_hd on sorders_hd.id=sorders_it.hd_id
left outer join porders_it on porders_it.isbn=books.isbn
left outer join porders_hd on porders_hd.id=porders_it.hd_id and porders_hd.so_id=sorders_hd.id
where porders_hd.id is null and books.kind=1;
```

The output result is:

```
so_id   so_dt       po_id   po_dt        isbn     dscr
1       2017-07-01  1       2017-07-02   12345    Book 1
(null)  (null)      2       2017-08-03   1111111  Book 2
2       2017-08-01  (null)  (null)       67890    Book 2
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9306/32/0)

The "trick" is to use union all with one of the two queries excluding records that linked both sides (to get the 'right' side of the FULL OUTER JOIN)

+1 to OP for providing the DDL and sample data!

I agree that the data model could be reworked, and could be normalized. The existing model still has at least the problem of a duplicate book record when a sales order and purchase order match (one of them is ignored). It seems to me that one improvement would be to have a master book list and include the id (or isbn if that is the primary key) from that table in porders_it and sorders_it, and eliminate the current books table.